# Dialog Box issues with Android Studio on OSX

Tags: macos, android-studio

Recently, whenever I have Android Studio in fullscreen mode, and a dialog box is presented, the dialog box disappears and I am unable to bring it back into focus so that I can start using the IDE again. I need to force quit the IDE and re-open and it is fine until the next dialog box is presented.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be from OSX 10.11 onwards, and has been reported by a number of users: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192746

I experienced the same issues on Android Studio v1.5. To save the hassle, I updated to Android Studio 2.0+ on the beta channel, which did not resolve the issue.

I agree, it is very annoying. Hopefully a workaround or patch will come soon.

Comment: Cmd + w closes down the active window even if it isn't visible, saves closing the whole app. May be helpful in the mean time. It is saving me time.

Comment: @CallumSmith - Yeah that does help, pressing esc also performs the same function.